# Реализация автоматического подключения к bluetooth устройству

Tags: c, linux, сокет, bluetooth

Первый вопрос: где сохраняются пины авторизованных bluetooth устройств?  
Второй вопрос: 
Есть код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <bluetooth/bluetooth.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci.h>
#include <bluetooth/hci_lib.h>
#include <bluetooth/rfcomm.h>

char *findBT();
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    struct sockaddr_rc addr = {0};
    int s, status;
    //char dest[18]="EC:FE:7E:11:85:1F";//тут должен быть мак адрес устройства....мак устройства с рфкомм EC:FE:7E:11:85:1F
    char *test;
    char *dest=NULL;
    //dest = findBT();
    printf("%c",test);
    // выделить сокет//прототип функции(нуль-терм.)
    test = (char *)malloc(18);
    dest=findBT();
    //test=findBT();
    s = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);
    //test = findBT();

    // устанавливаем параметры соединения
    addr.rc_family = AF_BLUETOOTH;
    addr.rc_channel = (uint8_t) 1;
    str2ba( dest, &addr.rc_bdaddr );

    // подключиться к серверу
    status = connect(s, (struct sockaddr *)&addr, sizeof(addr));

    // отправить сообщение
    if( status == 0 ) {
       printf("sdads");
    }

    if( status < 0 ) perror("uh oh");

    close(s);
    return 0;
}
char *findBT()//Функция для поиска 1(!!!) BT устройства с возвратом его мак адреса
 {
    inquiry_info *ii = NULL;
    int max_rsp, num_rsp;
    int dev_id, len, flags;
    int i,socketRfcomm;
    char addrf[19] = {0};//жать F7,что бы очистить от мусора.
    char name[248] = { 0 };
    socketRfcomm = socket(AF_BLUETOOTH, SOCK_STREAM, BTPROTO_RFCOMM);

    dev_id = hci_get_route(NULL);
    if (dev_id < 0 || socketRfcomm < 0) {
        //perror("opening socket");
        //exit(1);//прототип функции(нуль-терм.)
        socketRfcomm = hci_open_dev(dev_id);
        }

    len  = 8;
    max_rsp = 255;
    flags = IREQ_CACHE_FLUSH; //использование всех подключенных устройств, с удалением из шеша старых
    ii = (inquiry_info*)malloc(max_rsp * sizeof(inquiry_info));

    num_rsp = hci_inquiry(dev_id, len, max_rsp, NULL, &ii, flags);
    if( num_rsp < 0 ) perror("hci_inquiry");

    for (i = 0; i < num_rsp; i++) {
        ba2str(&(ii+i)->bdaddr, addrf);
        memset(name, 0, sizeof(name));
        if (hci_read_remote_name(socketRfcomm, &(ii+i)->bdaddr, sizeof(name),
            name, 0) < 0)
        //strcpy(name, "[unknown]");
        printf("%s  %s\n", addrf, name);
        //char *p=addrf;

    }
    printf ("Hi %c %d %s", 'c', 10, "there!");
    free( ii );
    close( socketRfcomm );

return strdup(addrf);
}
```

По сути, выполняется поиск и подключение к устройству, но требует пин-код, что не вариант, т.к. не дело заставлять юзера вводить 4 циферки. В QT есть реализация подключения без пина, так что это возможно. Как можно на си организовать? Что-то про прозрачный канал нашел, но ничего дельного. 
Да, и у всех устройств пин идентичный, быть может, получится задать этот самый пин по умолчанию?